# Count number of occurences of certain character in two strings with Python

Tags: python

I want to count the number of times both a occurs, and b occurs in both strings together, using recursion in Python.

For example if the input was ('aabb', 'bbba'), the output would be (3,5) because there are three a's and five b's total.

What I have tried:

```
def counting(string1, string2):    
   if not string1:
      return 0
   elif string1[0]=='a':
      return 1+counting(string[1:],string2)
   else:
      return counting(string[1:],string2)
```

Comment: @toptalent Be sure to leave an answer below, then!

Comment: Do you have to use recursions or can other methods be used?

Comment: for the input instead of counting(string1, string2) I would use counting(*strings) for that type of function if I were you.

Comment: What is the problem with what you've tried? i.e. what is your question?

Comment: The problem requires that the two parameters are the two strings, nothing else. And it can only be a single function

Answer (score -1):

Your mistake is referencing an invalid variable. You tried to access the variable `string` in this line:

```py
return counting(string[1:],string2)
```

... where it should have been `string1`. You can fix it like so:

```py
return counting(string1[1:],string2)
```

Answer (score -1):

Via `recursion`:

**`NOTE:`** If you merge both the strings before then you can further simplify this algorithm

```
def counting(s, v):
    if not s:
        return 0
    elif s[0] == v:
        return 1+counting(s[1:], v)
    else:
        return counting(s[1:], v)


def count(s1, s2):
    return (counting(s1, 'a') + counting(s1, 'b')), (counting(s2, 'a') + counting(s2, 'b'))

count('aaab','bba') # will print (4,3)
```

Via `Counter`:

You can merge both the string and then count value:

```
from collections import Counter
print(Counter(''.join(('aabb', 'bbba'))).values()) #[3,5]
```

updated function:

```
def counting(string1, string2):
    return Counter(string1+string2).values()
    
counting('aab','bbb')
```

Comment: The problem requires that the two parameters are the two strings, nothing else. And there is only one function

Answer (score -1):

#### UPDATE

Considering your specifiaction in the comments, I came up with this:

```py
def counting(string1: str, string2: str) -> tuple[int, int]:
    if not string1 and not string2:
        return 0, 0

    if not string1:
        str1a = str1b = 0
    elif string1[0] == "a":
        str1a, str1b = 1, 0
    else:
        str1a, str1b = 0, 1

    if not string2:
        str2a = str2b = 0
    elif string2[0] == "a":
        str2a, str2b = 1, 0
    else:
        str2a, str2b = 0, 1

    next_round = counting(string1[1:], string2[1:])

    return next_round[0] + str1a + str2a, next_round[1] + str1b + str2b


print(counting("aabb", "bbba"))

>> (3, 5)
```

#### Old answer:

Your recursive function is working pretty well, however keeping track of two variables with two letters each can become quite hard with recursion. I would suggest that you use your recursive function for counting the occurrence of one letter in one word at a time and then adding up the results.

In order to make it more extensible in the future (more/other words, more/other letters to count) you could create a function like this:

```py
# You only count the occurrence of one letter in one word.
def counting(string: str, letter: str) -> int:
    if not string:
        return 0
    elif string[0] == letter:
        return 1 + counting(string[1:], letter)
    else:
        return counting(string[1:], letter)


# here you add up the results
def get_all_occurrences(word_list: list[str], letter_list: list[str]) -> tuple[int]:
    letters_profile = []
    for letter in letter_list:
        letter_occurrences = 0
        for word in word_list:
            letter_occurrences += counting(word, letter)
        letters_profile.append(letter_occurrences)

    return tuple(letters_profile)


words = ["aabb", "abbb"]
letters = ["a", "b"]

occurrences = get_all_occurrences(words, letters)
print(occurrences)
```

Comment: The problem requires that the two parameters are the two strings, nothing else. And there is only one function